# How exactly is detection done before the slit in the double slit experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

We commonly hear that in the double slit experiment, detection of which slit the photon/electron passes through when the the detector is positioned before the slit, collapses the wave and results in particle like behaviour resulting in the 2 band results on the back wall.

Could someone please explain exactly what the detector before the slit is and how it works?

Comment: See the answers on Reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/3ebcw6/what_is_used_to_detect_electrons_in_the_double/

Comment: It's anything that makes "click!" when hit by a photon. You might as well put a black cardboard there... same effect.

Comment: @CuriousOne I think she probably wonders how it detects without derailing electron/photon's passage through the slit.

Comment: @Conifold: Well, then we need to say that there is no measurement that can do that. Interactions have to change the energy and momentum of the photon, which leads to a loss of interference or they will absorb the photon outright and... no interference, again.